# Identify $c/c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Let
>   $c=$ set of converging sequences
>   $c_0=$ set of sequences that
>   converge to $0$.
>   Find a set isomorphic to the quotient space
>   $c/c_0=\{ (a_n)+c_0: (a_n)\in c \}$

I have done a similar problem when $X$ is a hilbert space and $M$ is a closed subspace.
Where in that case the Quotient map $Q:X\rightarrow X/M$ that is $(Q(x)=x+M)$ restricted to the $M^{\perp}$ will become an isometric isomorphism.

But in the above mentioned question since they are not Hilbert spaces (Please correct me if I'm wrong)I cannot directly apply the quotient map to a perpendicular set. But I think there is an analogy.
Help would be appreciated

Comment: Hmm, at a wild guess I would imagine $c /c_0 \sim \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks but do you see a way to justify.

Comment: If $x \in c$ then $x-\lim_nx_n \in c_0$. Say $x \sim y$ **if** $\lim_n x = \lim_n y_n$.

Comment: You don't need the structure of a Hilbert space to do this.

Comment: Yeah but what I was thinking is that, If we can make use of the quotient map $Q:c\rightarrow c/c_0$ to a certain restricted domain in a way that it becomes an isomorphism.. then it will do the job

Comment: Well, you can make it more complicated if you like.

Comment: Haha. I don't want to.. Can you please explain a little bit more on your answer .  why  the equivalence relation is used and so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the mapping $l\colon c\to\mathbb{R}$, $l((x_n)):=\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$. This mapping is linear and surjective. The kernel equals $c_0$. Thus $c/c_0\sim l(c)=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank You so much!